# How to ensure views are well constraint even when they grow in context without pushing other views out of the layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to achieve the below in my xml but currently when I my textView does not wrap the text as exepcted but instead pushes the the text down and the imageButton far. I am wondering how can I achieve this having in mind the texts can be bigger and need to wrap and fit in nicely without pushing the button away? below is my code sample

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hospitalButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        app:image="@drawable/hospital_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineCenterButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:startsChecked="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="@color/white_"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hospitalGroup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hospitalButton" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/hospitalGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buttonDivider">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="@string/id_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/midTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Get ID" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/midTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:text="@string/mid_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/submitButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/submitbackground"
            android:src="@drawable/submit_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/animation"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/submitButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/submitButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/submitButton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/submitButton"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/spinner" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/submitGroupDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hospitalGroup" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it's not clear what you wanted to do but here is the solution you can apply to make your view as a picture you uploaded.

Just apply height & width of midTextView to 0dp

Note: don't know what your idTextView will do it's not clear as per your layout structure.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/idTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:text="@string/id_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Get ID" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/midTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:text="@string/mid_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/submitButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/idTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```